# Uploading unpermmited filetypes for virtual products on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, permissions, woocommerce, e-commerce

I would like to sell an eBook on my website.  I'm using WordPress and the shop uses woo commerce, which I just switched over to. 
The problem is, the eBook comes in a *folder*, which is not so simple to upload and sell.  If I upload an .exe file, I get the message "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons" and there are certain files in the eBook folder which generate the same error.

I can use WinRAR or similar to compress it and then upload it that way, but I can't assume my users will have the technical ability to know what to do with it once downloaded.

The alternatives I came up with: 
I have an install (.exe) file which is easy to download and use - it simply extracts everything and leaves shortcuts.
Ideally I would like to upload the entire folder and have the user be able to download the whole thing at once but, even if I could upload it, it doesn't seem possible to select an entire folder but only individual files - I would be really grateful if someone knew of a way to do this!

I'm yet to find a workable solution so any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Should have added this is for interactive eBooks, not a simple pdf, unfortunately.

Comment: Unless you only want to serve clients that use Windows O/S, the exe approach would fail for Mac, Linux and majority of mobile users. I am sure you would have already considered this but is PDF not an option for your eBook? Write up a step by step post along with screen grabs that details what to do with the downloaded .exe file, for clients who do not know what to do with the file once downloaded.

Comment: I would use .zip. I believe most Windows/Macs/Linux operating systems can open that automatically without special software.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Might just have to use .zip. As I edited in later, pdf won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting WordPress' internal restrictions on file / mime types for adding anything to their Media Library.

This plugin should allow you to add .exe as a valid mime type.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/

More details from the [WordPress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/2310-download-file_type-missing-in-variations-filters-exe/#post-6190215):

> The underlying WordPress function called get_allowed_mime_types is used which is filterable and can be customized based on your needs via the WordPress provided filter named upload_mimes which is documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes

---

> Thanks, WilltheWebMechanic. Your post helped me fix the issue without reverting to an older version of Woocommerce.
>
> If anyone else is wary of the functions.php file like I am, you can use a plugin for it.
>
> This is the one I used, and it seems nice and stable. Plus, it’s compatible with Woocommerce, which is why I chose it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/
>
> Once it’s installed, you can just add your file type to the ‘Mime’ section of the plugin.
>
> I just added the file types I needed (epub and mobi). I hit save and my products are all working again.